# PowerShell batch file to toggle show touch input panel

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, process

I need a batch file that when I run would show touch input panel (virtual keyboard) when hidden, otherwise if already visible then hide it. The path to the touch input panel is:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\tabtip.exe

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('TASKLIST ^| FINDSTR /i TabTip.exe') DO 
( IF "%ErrorLevel%"=="0" 
    ( TASKKILL /IM TabTip )
ELSE 
    ( start "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe" ) 
) 
PAUSE
```

Comment: What have you tried. Where are you stuck. Please show your work / code, the effort you have put into it.

Comment: i have tried the following but doesn't work (no errors either)

Comment: FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('TASKLIST ^| FINDSTR /i TabTip.exe') DO (
IF "%ErrorLevel%"=="0" (
TASKKILL /IM TabTip
) ELSE (
start "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe"
)
)
pause

Comment: Can you edit your question? It should work. This way you get syntax highligthing and people are more inclined to help and less inclined to downvote.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
# Settings
$ProcessName = "TabTip"
$Executable = "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\TabTip.exe"

# Get process
$Process = Get-Process -Name $ProcessName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Is it running?
If($Process)
{
    # Running

    # Kill this process
    $Process.Kill()
}
Else
{
    # Not running

    # Start the process
    Start-Process $Executable
}
```

I have tried killing it with

```
Stop-Process $Process
```

aswell as with

```
Stop-Process $Process.Id
```

but I'm always getting an access denied (not sure why).

However, the Kill() method worked fine, you should use this

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is probably the better choice nowadays (see existing answers), but it can be done by batch easily with a single line (not even needs a `for` loop):

```
TASKLIST | FINDSTR /i "TabTip.exe" && TASKKILL /f /IM TabTip.exe || "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe"
```

For better readabilty and expandability:

```
TASKLIST | FINDSTR /i "TabTip.exe" && (
    TASKKILL /f /IM TabTip.exe 2>nul
    echo killed.
) || (
    "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe"
    echo started.
)
```

Why your code didn't work:

- wrong `for` syntax: the opening `(` has to be on the same line as the `do`
- `%errorlevel%` is meaningless here, because the command in the `for` loop is executed in a new independent process, so you won't get back an errorlevel in the original process (your script) (aka. it's the same as before the loop).
- You need the `/f` (force) switch for `taskkill`, as TabTip is one of the few programs that doesn't properly exit on a close request.
- your `start` syntax is wrong: `start` takes the first quoted string as a Window Title (can be empty), so it should be `start "" "blahblah\app.exe"`
- you don't need the `start` command, as you are starting a GUI application.